Display Min. order amount on frontend Woocommerce
I'm trying to display the minimum order amount (per product) on my Woocommerce archive pages and on my single product pages
See here: https://webdesignvarsseveld.nl/groka/product-categorie/testcategorie/
The basic code snippet that I have used in functions.php I found online:
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_sku_to_archive' );

function add_sku_to_archive() {
  global $product;
  echo '<div class="sku">Artikelnummer: ' . $product->get_sku() . '<br />Bestelhoeveelheid: ' . $product->get_min_purchase_quantity() . '</div>';
}

The SKU shows fine, but I can't seem to display minimum order amount for that specific product. It's probably very simple, but I've wasted too much time already...
The plugin I use for the min/max quantities is this one: https://woocommerce.com/products/minmax-quantities/

The function $product->get_min_purchase_quantity() you are using is correct for woocommerce. However, since you are using a plugin which let's you input it through meta field, you can still retrieve and display the minimum quantity set by the plugin using WooCommerce’s built-in functions.
Here’s an example of how you can do this:
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_sku_to_archive' );

    function add_sku_to_archive() {
      global $product;
      // Variable storing the mini quantity value
      $min_purchase_quantity = $product->get_meta('_wc_min_qty_product'); // replace with your actual meta value
    
      echo '<div class="sku">Artikelnummer: ' . $product->get_sku() . '<br />Bestelhoeveelheid: ' . $min_purchase_quantity . '</div>';
    }

The _wc_min_qty_product is likely a meta key used by WooCommerce Min/Max Quantities plugin to store the minimum quantity for a product.
If this is not the correct meta key, you can check it by yourself the following way:

Go to the product edit page: Navigate to the edit page of the product for which you want to check the meta keys. In this case the minimum quantity field.



Inspect the input field: Right-click on the input field and select "Inspect" or "Inspect Element" from the context menu. This will open the browser’s developer tools and highlight the HTML code for the input field.
Find the meta key: In the HTML code, look for the name attribute of the input field. The value of this attribute is usually the meta key used to store the input field’s value in the database.
Replace the _wc_min_qty_product value from the above code with your actual value. Example: $product->get_meta('new_value_here');


That was very helpful! Got it all working now. I've added the min. purch. quantity to be set to 1 if not specified in the backend:
`
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'add_mpq_to_archive' );
function add_mpq_to_archive() {
global $product;
$min_purchase_quantity = $product->get_meta('minimum_allowed_quantity');
if (empty($min_purchase_quantity)) {
echo 'Artikel#: ' . $product->get_sku() . 'Bhh: 1';
} else {
echo 'Artikel#: ' . $product->get_sku() . 'Bhh: ' . $min_purchase_quantity . '';
}
}
`

When I take a look at the website you've provided, it is clear, that your solution works on product list.
It is because of woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook, which executes the code during the listing. On single product page, you have to use different hook. Take a look at this simple guide.
Solution, which would add the min. order amount could look like this:
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'add_sku_to_archive' );

function add_sku_to_archive() {
  global $product;
  echo '<div class="min-purchase-quantity">Bestelhoeveelheid: ' . $product->get_meta('minimum_allowed_quantity') . '</div>';
}

EDIT: Changed to correct function as @Richard mentioned.

Thanks! But we're not there yet... f.i. https://webdesignvarsseveld.nl/groka/product/polo/
I've set the minimum amount to 2, and that shows fine in the add to cart option, but  after 'Bestelhoeveelheid:' it shows 1.
So my guess is that $product->get_min_purchase_quantity() is not the right snippet?

@JaapVeldhorst I’ve looked at your website and it shows 2 to me. Which should be correct. Don’t you have some sort of a caching mechanic in place?

@Eduard, because now he uses $product->get_meta() function to retrieve the value of a specific meta field, from the plugin he uses.

@Richard right! Thought he had the correct function all the time. Nevertheless, I will update the answer. Thank you for clarifying.
